# pg_agent can't connect to server

Tags: postgresql, redhat, postgresql-14, pgagent

Good afternoon.

Red Hat 8.7.

Postgresql Pro Standard 14.8.

When execute:

```
pgagent_14 hostaddr=127.0.0.1 dbname=postgres user=postgres port=5432 password=somepassword
```

Error:
WARNING: Couldn't create the primary connection

Password checked in DBeaver.

Before I tried another method: create extension pg_agent in psql and got:

ERROR:  could not open extension control file "/opt/pgpro/std-14/share/extension/pgagent.control": No such file or directory